# iOS show alert if no internet connection in webview

Tags: ios, webview

I am making an app with a simple webview in xCode. I want the user to be notified if there is no internet connection available. When there is no internet connection there will be a pop up telling you "no internet connection available" and two options - Try again, and cancel. How do I do this? I am a beginner at this so please explain simple.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyWebPage.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Uhm, what research did you do exactly? SO is not your "do my code for me" site. This is very simple, but you should learn it yourself.

Comment: By having you to explain me how to do this I will be able to learn..

Comment: This is not a teaching site. Go learn from Apple documentation, and if you hit a problem, ask here by showing what you have tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Leo but Ill make a short attempt to explain it:

1. get the class Reachability from apple or github:
   -- it is a class that allows you to check for internet / see if a specific host can be reached / ....
2. in your viewController check for reachability before loading the website.. 
   -- maybe in viewWillAppear

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
           [super viewWillAppear:animated];        
           _reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
           [self handleReachability];

           //optional monitor
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(handleReachability: )
                                                        name:@"kReachabilityChangedNotification" object:nil];

           [_reachability startNotifier]; //! don't forget to remove the notification in viewWillDisappear  

       }
   ```
3. implement handle method e.g. to show a simple UIAlertView:

   ```
   -(void)handleReachability:(NSNotificationCenter*)notification{
       NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

       if(netStatus == NotReachable) {
           [self setNoInternet:YES];
           // what happens when network/server down: 
           if([webView isLoading]) {
               [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
               [webView stopLoading];
               hasLoaded = NO;
           }

       }else {
           [self setNoInternet:NO];
           if(![webView isLoading] && !hasLoaded) {
               hasLoaded = NO;
               [self load];
           }
       }
   }
   ```